# Override default Constructor of Dialog in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to override the default constructor of **CTestDialog** so that I can pass **CString** in it.

How do I pass

> `CTestDialog(CString strValue = NULL);`

Is this possible in MFC or is it just my imagination?

```
class CTestDialog : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CTestDialog)

public:
    CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    CTestDialog(CString strValue = NULL); // Custom Constructor
    virtual ~CTestDialog();

    // Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_TESTDIALOG };
#endif

protected:
    CString _filename;
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
};
```

Usage:

```
 CString str = _T("Some Text");

 CTestDialog dlg(str);
 dlg.doModal();
```

## UPDATE 1

On line:

```
dlg.DoModal();
```

> Debug Assertion Failed. Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Dialog is displayed.

## UPDATE 2

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CTestDialog, CDialog)

CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(IDD_TESTDIALOG, pParent)
{

}

CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CString str)
    : CDialog(CTestDialog::IDD, NULL)
{
    _filename = str;
}

CTestDialog::~CTestDialog()
{
}

void CTestDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestDialog, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CTestDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here
    AfxMessageBox(_filename.GetBuffer());
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Are you having some kind of trouble doing it?

Comment: yes, whenever i write the above code debug assertion dialog is displayed. I don't find the way to correctly do it. Any sample will be highly helpful

Comment: @TheUndeadFish in dlg.doModal() -> debug assertion occurs. Don't know what to do to solve it.

Comment: Are you calling the base constructor correctly? [C++, MFC: Supplying constructor arguments to a CDialog derived class correctly](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22973312/C-MFC-Supplying-constructor-arguments-to-a-CDialog-derived-class-correctly.html)

Comment: @crashmstr i have shared the code the way i am doing. but i don't know whether i am right or wrong. I am specifying new constructor instead of editing the default constructor.

Comment: Use your call stack and look at just what the assertion is. What is it?

Comment: No, you *don't* show us the *implementation* of the constructor, just the declaration. If you don't call the `CDialog` constructor like the "built-in" one does, things will fail.

Comment: Also, `CString strValue = NULL` is just wrong (even if it compiles).

Comment: @lakeweb  `INT_PTR CDialog::DoModal()
{
 // can be constructed with a resource template or InitModalIndirect
 ASSERT(m_lpszTemplateName != NULL || m_hDialogTemplate != NULL ||
  m_lpDialogTemplate != NULL);` Error is displayed here

Comment: @crashmstr removed the NULL value still debug assertion occurs

Comment: Which one is null in the ASSERT??

Comment: As far as I am aware you can only have **one** default constructor. A default constructor is one where all parameters are provided with default values. You have provided two default constructors. Remove the `= NULL` from the declaration of your custom constructor.

Comment: Also, I suggest your custom constructor has two parameters, the first `CWnd` pointer followed by your CString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
class CTestDialog : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CTestDialog)

   public:
      CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor

      CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent, CString strValue); // Custom Constructor

      virtual ~CTestDialog();

   // Dialog Data
   #ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
        enum { IDD = IDD_TESTDIALOG };
   #endif

   protected:
      CString _filename; 
      virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

      DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
   public:
      virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
};
```

And:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CTestDialog, CDialog)

CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(IDD_TESTDIALOG, pParent)
{

}

CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent, CString str)
    : CDialog(IDD_TESTDIALOG, pParent)
{
     _filename = str;
}

CTestDialog::~CTestDialog()
{
}

void CTestDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestDialog, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CTestDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here
    AfxMessageBox(_filename.GetBuffer());
    return TRUE; 
}
```

Notice:

```
CTestDialog::CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent, CString str)
    : CDialog(IDD_TESTDIALOG, pParent)
{
     _filename = str;
}
```

So it would be:

```
CTestDialog dlg(NULL, "filename");
dlg.DoModal();
```

You see, your custom constructor is called first. That then passes the required `pParent` into the base class constructor.

Comment: Using constructor to pass value from one dialog to another is good way of data transmission or any other preferable method is also there. And one more doubt. Is passing **pParent** in custom constructor is required or can be omitted also

Answer (score 0):

```
class CTestDialog : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CTestDialog)

   public:
      CTestDialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor

      CTestDialog(CString strValue); // Custom Constructor

      virtual ~CTestDialog();

   // Dialog Data
   #ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
        enum { IDD = IDD_TESTDIALOG };
   #endif

   protected:

      virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

      DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
   public:
      CString _filename; 
      virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
};
```

and In usage

```
 CTestDialog dlg(NULL, stingtopass);
 dlg.doModal();
```

Comment: It is still bad design to have two default constructors. You now create the object without specifying a parameter. So which constructor will it use? As I mentioned in the comments you should have removed `= NULL` from the declaration of your second constructor. It is also usually best to keep your variables private and add public Get or Set methods. Finally I don't see why you did not just add the variable as a parameter to the original constructor. You did not need two.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I accept your point. small question is tickling me, Question is whether to override default constructor or to use Get or Set methods as guided by you. Which one is more logical and good practice in mfc.

Comment: Either, or even both. They are both good practice techniques.